# How to make a common @Testcontainer for multiple Jupiter tests?

Tags: java, spring-boot, testcontainers, testcontainers-junit5

I have an abstract controller test class and its inheritor with units, but I want to separate tests into different classes according to the controller method they are testing. Every time I create the second test-class and put a test in it I get the following error:

`Failed to validate connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@28806954 (This connection has been closed.). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value.`

I have the following base class:

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@Testcontainers
public abstract class ControllerAbstractTest {
    @Container
    private final static PostgreSQLContainer postgreSQLContainer;

    static {
        postgreSQLContainer = new PostgreSQLContainer<>("postgres:13")
            .withDatabaseName("my-test-db")
            .withUsername("a")
            .withPassword("a");
        postgreSQLContainer.start();

        System.setProperty("spring.datasource.url", postgreSQLContainer.getJdbcUrl());
        System.setProperty("spring.datasource.password", postgreSQLContainer.getPassword());
        System.setProperty("spring.datasource.username", postgreSQLContainer.getUsername());
    }
    // other methods
```

Tests work just fine in a single inheritor class.

I am using `org.testcontainers:junit-jupiter:1.16.2`, same version for postgresql and `spring boot 2.5.6`. `@Test` annotation is from `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test`

I have tried adding `@Testcontainers` to inheritors and removing it from the base test class, but it did not help.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to start a container in a separate configuration so the test classes are not required to extend a specific abstract class.

```java
/**
 * Starts a database server in a local Docker container.
 */
@TestConfiguration
public class TestDatabaseConfiguration {

    private static final PostgreSQLContainer postgreSQLContainer = new PostgreSQLContainer<>("postgres:13")
            .withDatabaseName("my-test-db")
            .withUsername("username")
            .withPassword("password");

    static {
        postgreSQLContainer.start();

        System.setProperty("spring.datasource.url", postgreSQLContainer.getJdbcUrl());
        System.setProperty("spring.datasource.password", postgreSQLContainer.getPassword());
        System.setProperty("spring.datasource.username", postgreSQLContainer.getUsername());
    }
}
```

Test classes that want to connect to the single shared database server are annotated with:

```java
@Import(TestDatabaseConfiguration.class)
```

Answer (score 0):

A different solution but based on Test Container [docs](https://java.testcontainers.org/test_framework_integration/manual_lifecycle_control/)

```
@TestConfiguration
public class TestConfig {

    static final MySQLContainer<?> container;

    static {
        // Build MySQL container
        container = new MySQLContainer<>("mysql:latest")
                .withDatabaseName("sara_brand_db")
                .withUsername("sara")
                .withPassword("sara");

        // Start container
        container.start();
    }
}
```

Import `TestConfig` class

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@Import(TestConfig.class)
public abstract class AbstractIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired protected MockMvc MOCKMVC;
    @Autowired @Qualifier(value = "testMapper") protected ObjectMapper MAPPER;

    // Set database connection
    @DynamicPropertySource
    public static void properties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
        registry.add("spring.datasource.url", container::getJdbcUrl);
        registry.add("spring.datasource.username", container::getUsername);
        registry.add("spring.datasource.password", container::getPassword);
    }

    // For every test, validate DB is running
    @Test
    void databaseIsRunning() {
        assertTrue(container.isRunning());
        assertTrue(container.isCreated());
    }

}
```